# How to revert back the flag.?

Tags: feature-request, bug, flagging

Today while checking the availabe options in flag, unknowingly I flaged the following question,

[List Service CheckInFile clears the values of managed metadata fields](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89266/list-service-checkinfile-clears-the-values-of-managed-metadata-fields)

How to revert it, I dont want to burden the moderators :)

Comment: LOL! We don't handle that aweful many flags, so don't worry. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but no worries. We rather handle one flag to much, than one to few :)